# ASP MVC looking for column even through field is virtual

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to allow a user to set an association by looking up by name.

Unfortunately, even though I'm using virtual, ASP-MVC 4 is complaining that this is an invalid column name for this particular virtual field "VesselName". Here's the error:

> Invalid column name 'VesselName'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'VesselName'.

Here's my code:

```
public int VesselID { get; set; }
public virtual Vessel Vessel { get; set; }
public virtual string VesselName
{
    get
    {
        return Vessel.Name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            // make sure we use upper case
            VesselID = db.Vessels.Where(v => v.Name.Equals(value.ToUpper())).First().ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: What does `virtual` have to do with this?  Where is your `class`?

Comment: Invalid column name 'VesselName'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'VesselName'.

Source Error:

Comment: So this is an Entity Framework class?  Where's the rest of it?  What does your repository look like?

Comment: Yes, this is an Entity framework class. The rest of it is a very long and I'm not sure if it is relevant. (I literally just added in that last part of the method assuming Entity Framework was not going to be looking for a column becuase of virtual.) I am not using a repository, I am just using straight entity framework codefirst. I guess I need to tell Entitry framework to ignore the property somewhow.

Comment: Trying to create form fields that don't map to the database like in this episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

Comment: The `virtual` keyword only affects how .Net resolves which method to call.

Comment: try [NotMapped] attribute

Comment: Yep. `[NotMapped]` is all you need; `virtual` is just for navigation properties.

Comment: @Nilesh - If you want some points feel free to answer the question. Once you do, I'll vote and accept as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have "virtual" or "unmapped" attributes in Entity framweork by using the `[NotMapped]` DataAnnotation. Virtual as used in the program refers to something else.

See virtual method tables.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: Your issue is not related to `virtual`